# Devise Logout - Cucumber step fails but application runs correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, cucumber, declarative-authorization

Ruby-2.2.0
Rails-4.2
Devise-3.4.1
Declarative_Authorization-0.5.7

I am converting a Rails-3.2 app to Rails-4.  The app employs both Devise authentication and Declarative Authorization.  I am using the default Devise controller.

At this juncture I have most of the authentication scenarios passing.  What I have run into however is that I cannot logout through Cucumber but I can in the browser.  The step in question looks like this:

```
 When /select end the current session/ do
  selector_type = "#"
  selector_value = link = "session_end_action_id"
  selector = selector_type + selector_value
  click_button( selector_value )
end
```

The routes look like this:

```
. . .
                  new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                                        devise/sessions#new
                      user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                                        devise/sessions#create
              destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)                                       devise/sessions#destroy
                     user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)                                       devise/passwords#create
                 new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)                                   devise/passwords#new
                edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)                                  devise/passwords#edit
                                   PATCH  /users/password(.:format)                                       devise/passwords#update
                                   PUT    /users/password(.:format)                                       devise/passwords#update
                       user_unlock POST   /users/unlock(.:format)                                         devise/unlocks#create
                   new_user_unlock GET    /users/unlock/new(.:format)                                     devise/unlocks#new
                                   GET    /users/unlock(.:format)                                         devise/unlocks#show
                           account POST   /account(.:format)                                              users#create
                       new_account GET    /account/new(.:format)                                          users#new
                      edit_account GET    /account/edit(.:format)                                         users#edit
                                   GET    /account(.:format)                                              users#show
                                   PATCH  /account(.:format)                                              users#update
                                   PUT    /account(.:format)                                              users#update
                                   DELETE /account(.:format)                                              users#destroy
                      authenticate GET    /authenticate(.:format)                                         devise/sessions#new

. . .

                    users#index
                                   POST   /users(.:format)                                                users#create
                          new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                                            users#new
                         edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                                       users#edit
                              user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                                            users#show
                                   PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)                                            users#update
                                   PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                                            users#update
                                   DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                                            users#destroy

. . .
```

The code in the view looks like this:

```
  <%-if current_user-%>
  <span class="authenticated_session" id="authenticated_session">
  <%=button_to( I18n.t( :session_end ).strip.titleize, 
      :destroy_user_session, 
      :class => "button logout",
      :confirm => I18n.t( :session_end_confirm ).strip.titleize,
      :id => :session_end_action_id,
      :method => :delete, 
      :title => I18n.t( :session_end_logout ).strip.titleize )-%>
  </span
<%-else-%>
  <%=button_to( I18n.t( :session_start ).strip.titleize, 
      :new_user_session, 
      :class => "button login",
      :id => :session_start_action_id_top, 
      :method => :get, 
      :title => I18n.t( :session_start_login ).strip.titleize )-%>
<%-end-%>
```

When I am authenticated and press the logout button then I am logged out.  When I run the cucumber step I get an authorisation error from Declarative Authorization.

```
  <p class='security classified' style='color: orangered'>
      you are not authorised to access the requested resource</p>    
  <br/>
  <!-- End of header section from layouts/application.html.erb -->
```

This is generated here in the application controller:

```
def permission_denied
  if current_user
    flash[:security_classified] =  I18n.t( :security_classified ).strip
  else
    flash[:security_restricted] =  I18n.t( :security_restricted ).strip
  end
  redirect_back_or_default( welcome_url )
end
```

and that is apparently being called from the Users controller:

```
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 21]]

  Rendered public/hll_authorisation_notice.html (0.1ms)

  Rendered welcome/show.html.erb within layouts/application (3.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 105ms (Views: 100.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)

Started DELETE "/users/sign_out" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-26 15:19:48 -0500

Processing by UsersController#destroy as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"sign_out"}
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users"
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 21]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users"
  Role Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "clearances" ON "roles"."id" = "clearances"."role_id" WHERE "clearances"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 21]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users"

Redirected to http://www.example.com/welcome
Filter chain halted as :filter_access_filter rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 23ms (ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)

Started GET "/welcome" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-26 15:19:48 -0500
Processing by WelcomeController#show as HTML
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users"
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 21]]

  Rendered public/hll_authorisation_notice.html (0.1ms)

  Rendered welcome/show.html.erb within layouts/application (1.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 61ms (Views: 57.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)
   (0.4ms)  rollback transaction
```

Inspecting (reformatted for this purpose) the object in the permission_denied method reveals this:

```
    #<UsersController:0x00000006ba52d8 @_action_has_layout=true,
 @_routes=nil, @_headers={"Content-Type"=>"text/html"}, @_status=200,
 @_request=#<ActionDispatch::Request:0x00000006ba51c0
 @env={"rack.version"=>[1, 3], "rack.input"=>#<StringIO:0x00000006c378e0>,
 "rack.errors"=>#<StringIO:0x00000006c379a8>, "rack.multithread"=>false,
 "rack.multiprocess"=>true, "rack.run_once"=>false,
 "REQUEST_METHOD"=>"DELETE", "SERVER_NAME"=>"www.example.com",
 "SERVER_PORT"=>"80", "QUERY_STRING"=>"", "PATH_INFO"=>"/users/sign_out",
 "rack.url_scheme"=>"http", "HTTPS"=>"off", "SCRIPT_NAME"=>"",
 "CONTENT_LENGTH"=>"14", "rack.test"=>true, "REMOTE_ADDR"=>"127.0.0.1",
 "HTTP_REFERER"=>"http://www.example.com/",
 "HTTP_HOST"=>"www.example.com",
 "CONTENT_TYPE"=>"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
 "HTTP_COOKIE"=>"_proforma_session=. . .
```

So, this is definitely an issue with the Users Controller. But error is only encountered during a Cucumber run.  When I serve the application with Rails server and access it from a browser, sign in and sign off then I am logged out without any error as shown in log extract below.

```
Started DELETE "/users/sign_out" for ::1 at 2015-01-26 15:45:50 -0500
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#destroy as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"Xl9Ui1a6jt8gyjZOuh0lsefUqFI1eEunaXivaEdfwWhMofYhYbRumnZlsRQjwmjWiC1C7sI7O3FwDgEf9lJzJw=="}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users"
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.4ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "accessed_at" = '2015-01-26 20:45:50.179843', "changed_at" = '2015-01-26 20:45:50.180748', "lock_version" = 20 WHERE ("users"."id" = 1 AND "users"."lock_version" = 19)
   (103.2ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
```

Has anyone any ideas as to what might be happening here?  Is the token value found in the browser sign_out significant?

P.S.  If I just do this:

```
visit('/users/sign_out')
```

then the step passes.  I am taking a wild guess here but is there anything about the javscript used with html buttons in RoR that might be causing what I am seeing?

Comment: Have you looked at the obvious, that when you are running the cucumber step you are not logged in!

Comment: Yes, the test is logged in.  One cannot get an authorisation error until one has authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

I think that I have discovered what was wrong; accidentally whilst researching a different and unrelated problem.

The issue I believe is the default testing method used by Capybara:

https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#selecting-the-driver

> By default, Capybara uses the :rack_test driver, which is fast but
>   limited: it does not support JavaScript, nor is it able to access HTTP
>   resources outside of your Rack application, such as remote APIs and
>   OAuth services. To get around these limitations, you can set up a
>   different default driver for your features. For example if you'd
>   prefer to run everything in Selenium, you could do:
>
> `Capybara.default_driver = :selenium`
>
> However, if you are using RSpec or Cucumber, you may instead want to
>   consider leaving the faster `:rack_test` as the default_driver, and
>   marking only those tests that require a JavaScript-capable driver
>   using `:js => true` or `@javascript`, respectively. By default,
>   JavaScript tests are run using the `:selenium driver`. You can
>   change this by setting `Capybara.javascript_driver`.
>
> You can also change the driver temporarily (typically in the
>   Before/setup and After/teardown blocks):
>
> `Capybara.current_driver = :webkit # temporarily select different driver`
>   `... tests ...` 
>   `Capybara.use_default_driver       # switch back to default driver`
>
> Note: switching the driver creates a new session, so you may not be
>   able to switch in the middle of a test.